# Why am I not getting overflow when I operate on values more than 2^15 - 1 for int values?

Tags: c, overflow

So here is the question:
INT_MAX is defined as 2^15 - 1. As I understand if we operate on values more than 32767 we should get an overflow. But why then I get correct answer doing this

```
int r = 32767 + 10000;
```

I get correct result!
How is it not causing overflow? And what is max number for int and double that if you go beyond it you get an overflow.

- I am using C for my testing

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you testing this in?

Comment: @PTNPNX Which compiler are you using and which language standard are you compiling against?

Comment: @PTNPNX wit a signed int, the maximum value is -32767 and +32767. However an unsigned int would be 0 to 65535.

Answer (score 5):

> INT_MAX is defined as 2^15 - 1

Is it? Did you print it and confirm that it was so for your compilation platform? The value 2<sup>15</sup>-1 is only the minimum bound for the value of `INT_MAX` on a standard-compliant C compiler.

C11 5.2.4.2.1:1:

> … Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> …
>
> — maximum value for an object of type int
>
> INT_MAX +32767   //2<sup>15</sup>−1

Comment: Okay, probably I misunderstood what manual says!
I though everything that is  equal or greater to 2^15-1 will overflow

Comment: Note that on platforms following the SysV-ABI (e.g. almost all Unices), an `int` has 32 bits so `INT_MAX` is typically 2147483647 = 2³¹-1.

Comment: @FUZxxl: POSIX **requires** at least 32 bits for `int`. So you won't find any current Unix without it.

Comment: @R.. My wording is like it is because there are platforms where `INT_MAX` is equal to 2⁶³ - 1 = 9223372036854775807 and there might be platforms with even larger integers in the future. It's a bad design decision to have such large integers though as this leaves one without a primitive 32 bit type, assuming `short` remains 16 bits.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Not necessarily. The compiler may very well provide build-in types which will then be typedef'ed in stdint.h to the 32 and 64 bit types. gcc does that for instance. int is not definedc to provide you with a given max. size (why should it?), but to be the most performant integer type for the given architecture. Also, one could emulate smaller types by masking. Not my prefeence, but there are/were architectures which had to (e.g. early ARMs had no 16 bit load/store and DEC Alpha had no 8 bit load/store afair). So, use(!) stdint if you need fixed-size types!

Comment: @Olaf I was saying “primitive” type as in “type like `char`, `int`, `double`, etc.” Remember that the original ISO 9899 does not specify `stdint.h` and some people like to program against that standard.

Comment: Well, C90 should not be a reference anymore. In general, no version of the standard does guarantee a certain size for the standard scalars, or even a certain encoding for signed integers (which is the problem when assigning an int to an unsigned). If you need distinct sizes, you have to use stdint and make sure that actually defines the type of the required size. In C90 there is no standard naming scheme at all for defined size integers. Btw. this is the reason for the wildwuchs in projects requiring this - C99 just came too late.

Comment: Note: I very well know the fact there are still ppl outside who stick to C90. However, even MISRA has moved forward and some parts of C99 can be easily added to C90 projects, too. stdint is such a thing: most times the header can just be taken from a C99 installation; there is a similar issue with stdatomic from C11 for gcc 4.7/8. Atleast one can define the required types from stdint; most projects only require a very small subset.

Comment: Just to state it clear: if you want to conform to C90 standard, you cannot assue a certain size of any type, but only a minimum size! Since C99 there is at least the possibility to have defined-size integers, but that is still optional.

Answer (score 5):

> `INT_MAX` is defined as 2^15 - 1

Not necessarily - have you double checked on your platform? Most of the times it's 2^31-1.

The *minimum* value in any platform is 2^15-1, but most computers today will use 32 or 64 bits integers.